# Sharepoint 2013 Upload image javascript from html canvas DataURL

Tags: javascript, image-upload

I try to upload image from dom element with canvas ( html2canvas.js ). and then i get dataURL() from canvas to upload.  Upload is successful but i cant open my file. like a without file extention.

Here my code ;

```
 html2canvas(document.getElementById("wedding1"), {
    letterRendering: 1,
    allowTaint: true,
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      console.log(canvas);
    }
  }).then(canvas => {
    var imageData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    imageData.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
    let canvasImg = document.getElementById("canvasimg");
    canvasImg.appendChild(canvas);
      this.uploadFile("selam.png", imageData);

  });
uploadFile(name, content) {
  var createitem = new SP.RequestExecutor(
    _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl
  );
  createitem.executeAsync({
    url:
      _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +
      "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/DuyuruDocument')/Files/Add(url='" +
      name +
      "',overwrite=true)",
    method: "POST",
    binaryStringRequestBody: true,
    body: content,
    success: function(e) {
      alert("done");
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("Error");
    },
    state: "Update"
  });
},
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason you have used "SP.RequestExecutor" ?

Comment: no, anyway doing that other way sir ?

Answer (score 0):

i solve that problem. It has to be raw ! here my codes ;

```
   function convertDataURIToBinary(dataURI) {
  var BASE64_MARKER = ";base64,";
  var base64Index = dataURI.indexOf(BASE64_MARKER) + BASE64_MARKER.length;
  var base64 = dataURI.substring(base64Index);
  var raw = window.atob(base64);
  return raw;}
```